# Unexpected global variable read result in C++ using avr-gcc for (local variable access is as expected)

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, global-variables, avr, avr-gcc

I am getting unexpected global variable read results when compiling the following code in avr-gcc 4.6.2 for ATmega328:

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define LED_PORT            PORTD
#define LED_BIT             7
#define LED_DDR             DDRD

uint8_t latchingFlag;

int main() {
    LED_DDR = 0xFF;
    for (;;) {
        latchingFlag=1;
        if (latchingFlag==0) {
            LED_PORT ^= 1<<LED_BIT; // Toggle the LED
            _delay_ms(100);         // Delay
            latchingFlag = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the entire code. I would expect the LED toggling to never execute, seeing as `latchingFlag` is set to `1`, however the LED blinks continuously. If `latchingFlag` is declared local to `main()` the program executes as expected: the LED never blinks.

The disassembled code doesn't reveal any gotchas that I can see, here's the disassembly of the main loop of the version using the global variable (with the delay routine call commented out; same behavior)

```
  59                .L4:
  27:main.cpp      ****     for (;;) {
  60                    .loc 1 27 0
  61 0026 0000              nop
  62                .L3:
  28:main.cpp      ****         latchingFlag=1;
  63                    .loc 1 28 0
  64 0028 81E0              ldi r24,lo8(1)
  65 002a 8093 0000         sts latchingFlag,r24
  29:main.cpp      ****         if (latchingFlag==0) {
  66                    .loc 1 29 0
  67 002e 8091 0000         lds r24,latchingFlag
  68 0032 8823              tst r24
  69 0034 01F4              brne .L4
  30:main.cpp      ****             LED_PORT ^= 1<<LED_BIT; // Toggle the LED
  70                    .loc 1 30 0
  71 0036 8BE2              ldi r24,lo8(43)
  72 0038 90E0              ldi r25,hi8(43)
  73 003a 2BE2              ldi r18,lo8(43)
  74 003c 30E0              ldi r19,hi8(43)
  75 003e F901              movw r30,r18
  76 0040 3081              ld r19,Z
  77 0042 20E8              ldi r18,lo8(-128)
  78 0044 2327              eor r18,r19
  79 0046 FC01              movw r30,r24
  80 0048 2083              st Z,r18
  31:main.cpp      ****             latchingFlag = 1;
  81                    .loc 1 31 0
  82 004a 81E0              ldi r24,lo8(1)
  83 004c 8093 0000         sts latchingFlag,r24
  27:main.cpp      ****     for (;;) {
  84                    .loc 1 27 0
  85 0050 00C0              rjmp .L4
```

The lines 71-80 are responsible for port access: according to the datasheet, `PORTD` is at address `0x2B`, which is decimal `43` (cf. lines 71-74).

The only difference between local/global declaration of the `latchingFlag` variable is how `latchingFlag` is accessed: the global variable version uses `sts` (store direct to data space) and `lds` (load direct from data space) to access `latchingFlag`, whereas the local variable version uses `ldd` (Load Indirect from Data Space to Register) and `std` (Store Indirect From Register to Data Space) using register `Y` as the address register (which can be used as a stack pointer, by avr-gcc AFAIK).  Here are the relevant lines from the disassembly:

```
  63 002c 8983              std Y+1,r24

  65 002e 8981              ldd r24,Y+1

  81 004a 8983              std Y+1,r24
```

The global version also has `latchingFlag` in the .bss section.  I am really not what to attribute the different global vs. local variable behavior to.  Here's the avr-gcc command-line (notice `-O0`):

```
/usr/local/avr/bin/avr-gcc \
    -I. -g -mmcu=atmega328p -O0 \
    -fpack-struct \                                                 
    -fshort-enums \                                         
    -funsigned-bitfields \                                        
    -funsigned-char \                                                 
    -D CLOCK_SRC=8000000UL \
    -D CLOCK_PRESCALE=8UL \
    -D F_CPU="(CLOCK_SRC/CLOCK_PRESCALE)" \
    -Wall \
    -ffunction-sections \
    -fdata-sections \
    -fno-exceptions \
    -Wa,-ahlms=obj/main.lst \
    -Wno-uninitialized \
    -c main.cpp -o obj/main.o
```

With `-Os` compiler flags the loop is gone from the disassembly, but can be forced to be there again if `latchingFlag` is declared `volatile`, in which case the unexpected persists for me.

Comment: Probably, global memory location is periodically cleared by erroneous code in other part of program.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff what other part of the program do you think might be doing it?  I posted the entire source code.

Comment: When I add `-Werror -O0` to the command line the compiler throws an error: `functions from <util/delay.h> won't work as designed" [-Werror=cpp]`. When I change it to `-Werror -Os` the error disappears.

Comment: Yes, the delay functions are dependent on `-O` != `0`. The unexpected behavior occurs regardless of whether delay functions are used or not and the behavior described above is the same whether `util/delay.h` is `#include`d or not.

Comment: Where are `_delay_ms(100)` lines in your disassembler listing?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff As noted in the question, the `_delay_ms(100)` call was removed when producing the disassembly. The behavior is identical whether the `_delay_ms()` call is made or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16046039/1264426) suggestion is almost exactly right: the SRAM variable is mapped to the wrong memory address. The `latchingFlag` variable is not at `0x0100` address, which is the first valid SRAM address, but is mapped to `0x060`, overlapping the `WDTCSR` register. This can be seen in the disassembly lines like the following one:

```
lds r24, 0x0060
```

THis line is supposed to load the value of `latchingFlag` from SRAM, and we can see that location `0x060` is used instead of `0x100`.

The problem has to with a [bug in the binutils](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13697) which two conditions are met:

- The linker is invoked with `--gc-sections` flag (compiler options: `-Wl,--gc-sections`) [to save code space](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/Compilation-options.html)
- None of your SRAM variables are initialized (i.e. initialized to non-zero values)

When both of these conditions are met, the `.data` section gets removed. When the `.data` section is missing, the SRAM variables start at address `0x060` instead of `0x100`.

One solution is to reinstall [binutils](http://www.sourceware.org/binutils/): the current versions have this bug fixed.  Another solution is to edit your linker scripts: on Ubuntu this is probably in `/usr/lib/ldscripts`. For ATmega168/328 the script that needs to be edited is `avr5.x`, but you should really edit all them, otherwise you could run into this bug on other AVR platforms. The change that needs to be made is the following one:

```
   .data   : AT (ADDR (.text) + SIZEOF (.text))
   {
      PROVIDE (__data_start = .) ;
-     *(.data)
+     KEEP(*(.data))
```

So replace the line `*(.data)` with `KEEP(*(.data))`. This ensures that the `.data` section is not discarded, and consequently the SRAM variable addresses start at `0x0100`

Answer (score 2):

According to your disassembler listing, `latchingFlag` global variable is located at RAM address 0.  This address corresponds to mirrored register `r0` and is not a valid RAM address for global variable.

Comment: I am not sure I see where you are seeing that, exactly, but the idea might be on the right track. Using `avr-objdump` to disassemble the code I see `lds r24, 0x0060`.  0x0060 is mapped to `WDTCSR` on ATmega328, but `WDTCSR` should not read `0`, since `WDTON` is not programmed, and therefore should read `1`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

After couple checks and code compares in EE chat I noticed that my version of avr-gcc (4.7.0) stores the value for `latchFlag` in `0x0100`, whereas [Egor Skriptunoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16046039/1264426) mentioned SRAM addres `0` being in OP's assembly listing.

Looking at OP's disassembly (the avr-dump version), I noticed that OP's compiler (4.6.2) stores `latchFlag` value in a different address (specifically, `0x060`) than my compiler (version 4.7.0), which stores `latchFlag` value at address `0x0100`.

My advice is to **update the avr-gcc version to at least version 4.7.0.** The advantage of 4.7.0 rather than latest and greatest available is the ability to compare the generated code again with my findings.

Of course if 4.7.0 solves the issue, then there is harm in upgrading to a more recent version (if available).

Comment: Well, it isn't the compiler _per se_: using 4.7.3 on cygwin I got `latchingFlag` at `0x060`, and using 4.7.0 on Ubuntu I got it at `0x100`. Just posted this to the avr-gcc list.